# FacebookConnect returns AccessToken without an expiration date

Tags: codenameone

If I use native FB login on an iPhone, the returned AccessToken doesn't seem to have an expiration date, unlike the one I get using browser based (non-native) login. Is this by design? The reason I ask is that the Parse.com API requires a valid expiration date. For now, I just use today's date plus three years.

Answer (score 0):

It does have that within the [AccessToken](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/AccessToken.html#getExpires--) class. See this [example of usage](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/building-a-chat-app-with-codename-one-part-2.html) in the Google login portion of the chat tutorial although it's applicable for Facebook too.